# Data type in RDD appears to be java.lang.Long, but map function gives a type mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This confusion is probably due to my Scala ignorance.

```
scala> spark.range(2).toDF("number").rdd.map(x => x(0).getClass).collect
res155: Array[Class[_]] = Array(class java.lang.Long, class java.lang.Long)
```

Apparently the types are Longs. Unfortunately, when I try to map a function, map() seems to want a String:

```
scala> spark.range(2).toDF("number").rdd.map(x => x(0)+22).collect
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(22)
 required: String
   spark.range(2).toDF("number").rdd.map(x => x(0)+22).collect
                                                   ^
```

What is going on? A colleague pointed me to the Spark documentation, where we have,

> ... in Spark 2.0, DataFrames are just Dataset of Rows in Scala and Java API. These operations are also referred as “untyped transformations” in contrast to “typed transformations” come with strongly typed Scala/Java Datasets.

This doesn't seem to be related to the problem, however, because the result of getClass() appears to be java.lang.Long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that accessing elements in a `Row` (the `x` in the map function) using only `x(0)` will result in `Any` as data type. Instead, tell Spark that it is a `Long` when accessing the value using `getAs`:

```
spark.range(2).toDF("number").rdd.map(x => x.getAs[Long](0)).collect
```

You can use the column name instead of the index to make it clearer:

```
spark.range(2).toDF("number").rdd.map(x => x.getAs[Long]("number")).collect
```

Even better would be to convert the dataframe to a dataset and not an rdd:

```
spark.range(2).toDF("number").as[Long].collect
```

Answer (score 0):

> map() seems to want a String:

`map` doesn't want a `String`, `+` does. As Ramesh's answer says, `x(0)` has type `Any`. While you can't add a number to `Any`, you [can](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html) add a `String`. There have been requests to remove this conversion over time because it's quite rarely actually desired, but it's still there.